# What's the benefit and why gdb differs from MethodName AND MethodName::<static var>

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

That one surprised me, when doing [tab](/questions/tagged/tab) for auto complete for a breakpoint it appeared two options to the same method.

```
test::TestFoo::SendFoo(short)
test::TestFoo::SendFoo(short)::fooID
```

On cpp:

```
bool TestFoo::SendFoo( short x )
{
   ...
   static unsigned int fooID = 0;
```

Why gdb differs? what's the benefit of using one or another?

Question tagged as C++ to avoid any missunderstanding from C static.

```
gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-56.el6)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SendFoo::fooID` and `SendFoo` are two different kinds of symbols, and I can imagine there will be a difference in the two breakpoints gdb offers you - although I am not very familiar with it:

The line where `fooID` is defined/initialized will be only hit once in the whole program, so a breakpoint in that line should be hit only once as well. A function level breakpoint should be hit every time the function gets called, so there is a major difference.

AFAIK the function scope `static` means the same for both C and C++ - a variable that is shared between all calls of that function and initialized the first time the function gets called.

Comment: I can't test it righ now, but would be that in 3 call to SendFoo, the following will happen:
SendFoo::fooID
SendFoo
SendFoo
So with b SendFoo I'll catch only the second and the third, or the 3 as a generical form.

Comment: You should get *every* call with the function level breakpoint, not only the 2nd and 3rd. The order in which the breakpoints get hit should be `SendFoo` - `SendFoo::fooId` - `SendFoo` - `SendFoo`. This is assuming that `fooId` is a static at function scope, not e.g. inside some conditional block inside the function. In that case the `fooId` breakpoint would be hit the first time the program enters the conditional block.